# Display Language selection menu for one subtitle

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, subtitle

I'm using jwplayer and I need to display the language selection menu, even when the video has only one CC(subtitle) available. 
Currently, the menu will only displayed for videos with multiple subtitles but in the case where's only one subtitle available, the "CC" button is used instead to turn it off and on and the menu will not display.

The documentation doesn't seem to mention this is even possible, so any ideas on how I should go about implementing this (or if it's even an option)  will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to show the language menu if there is only one thing to show anyway? Is this question really about "How to turnoff subtitles"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality for this as the detection of a supported closed caption file type is required to render that option in the CC menu. You may want to check to the documentation to learn more about this feature https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407438-adding-closed-captions